# FCM not loading Properties for configured Hyper-V shares

Tags: hyper-v, network-share, failovercluster, file-server

Have 3 nodes 2 of which are part of a hyper-v cluster. Many moons ago I configured network shares within FCM, for the last few days when attempting to select properties for specific shares it displays the below:

[image: Picture]

I have restarted all nodes.

I have confirmed i **can** PSSession to the server my PC.

I have confirmed WinRM **can** communicate to the remote Nodes with:

```
winrm id -r:ComputerName
```

I can confirm i do **not** have a loopback ip configured:

```
netsh http show ip listen
```

I have confirmed i do **not** have any proxy configured:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

I have confirmed that WMI is also working as to be expected.

The issue is happening on certain pc’s in the network, other PC’s in the network can still access it, when using my credentials on the working PC's i am able to view the properties.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Can you confirm this is only a problem with Failover Cluster Manager running on various PC's in your network, and NOT a problem with the actual shares ? .... so FCM is working properly on the cluster nodes itself, and the shares are all online ? --- please update your post with this information.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. The FCM is working on the HOST servers and some other systems. We have rebuilt two seperate WIN 10 systems and they have the same issue. I am not sure if it being caused by an update or something. Doing my head in.

Comment: OK, please confirm: on PC-A (with your credentials) FCM is working, and on PC-B (with your credentials FCM is not working.... right ?

Answer (score 0):

All - I raised an issue with Microsoft and after hours of troubleshooting got no where.

The good news is I found the problem myself, I have found the solution to the issue myself.

It turns out the version of RSAT being offered by Microsoft for windows 10 (WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu) appears to be have the issue, do not use FCM from the new version of RSAT from the URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=45520

After getting a package output from my working colleges PC I noticed a difference with the RSAT versions, see below:

Non-Working:

Package Identity : Microsoft-Windows-RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Client-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.347
State : Installed
Release Type : Update
Install Time : 5/12/2016 1:50 AM

Working:

Package Identity : Microsoft-Windows-RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Client-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14300.1041
State : Installed
Release Type : Update
Install Time : 3/02/2017 12:43 AM

I removed the .347 version from my PC and installed the .1041 RSAT version from my colleges PC, after doing this all is working perfectly. Thanks Microsoft for the great undocumented feature!